# JavaScript popup to show only once

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

this is a script for popup fade in box which shows when user wants to leave webpage.

I am trying to make it show only once, so when the user clicks "X mark" to exit, I don't want to show it again. Currently it show always, no matter how many times you have click to exit.

Would appreciate any help, as I have very limited knowledge in javascript.

javascript

```
$(document).ready(function() {

    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

        $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - $('#exitpopup').width()/2));
        $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - $('#exitpopup').height()/2));

        if(e.clientY <= 30)
        {
            // Show the exit popup
            $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
            $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();   
        }
    });

    $('#xmark').click(function(){
        $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
        $('#exitpopup').slideUp();
    }); 

});
```

.css

```
#exitpopup {
    text-align:center;
    font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
#exitpopup h1 {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    font-size:55px;
}
#exitpopup h2 {
    margin-top:0px;
    padding-top:0px;
    font-size:35px;
    text-transform:uppercase;
    color: #ff5300;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-style:italic;
}
#exitpopup p {
    text-align:left;
}
.button-popup {
    background-color: #ff5300;
    padding:40px;
    color:#fff;
    border:0px;
    font-size:26px;
    font-weight:bold;
}
.input-popup {
    border: 5px solid white;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
              0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    -moz-box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
              0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    box-shadow: 
        inset 0 0 8px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1), 
              0 0 16px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
    padding: 15px;
    background: #FFE2C6;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size:16px;
}
#xmark {
    position:absolute;
    margin-left:-20px;
    margin-top:-40px;
}
```

html

```
<div style="display: none; width:100%; height:100%; position:fixed; background:#000000; opacity: .9; filter:alpha(opacity=0.8); z-index:999998; margin-top:-15px;" id="exitpopup_bg"></div>

<div style=" margin-left: -20px; width:1000px; height:550px; display:none; position:fixed; color:#000; padding:40px 20px 20px 20px;   z-    index:999999; background:rgb(20, 20, 20); background: #f7f7f7; " id="exitpopup"> 

<div id="xmark"><img src="../slike/x-mark.png" /></div> 
</div>
```

Comment: When you say you "don't want to show it again", do you mean don't show it but reset when the page refreshes (so a refreshed page will show it again), or don't show it ever again period?

Comment: reset when the page refreshes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could just add a counter variable. Something like this:

```
    $(document).ready(function() {
    var counter=0;
            ....
     if(counter ==0) {
        // Show the exit popup
        $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
        $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();   
        counter++;
      }
 } 
  });
```

Comment: `counter` is initialized to 0, so it will never be less than 0. This will never open. Should be `counter == 0`.

Comment: The problem is that the box needs to show up only when users mouse leaves the document at the top (when user wants to exit the page). It can take minutes until the user decides to leave. You can see the script in action here: http://www.brzedijete.com/test/rezultatiFU.php

Comment: On this I just edited/added if(counter ==0 && e.clientY <= 30)  and it works just like I wanted :) Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can just keep a variable around as a flag of whether the popup has been opened or not. It'll get set back to false when the page refreshes.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var opened = false;
    $(document).mousemove(function(e) {

        $('#exitpopup').css('left', (window.innerWidth/2 - $('#exitpopup').width()/2));
        $('#exitpopup').css('top', (window.innerHeight/2 - $('#exitpopup').height()/2));

        if(e.clientY <= 30 && !opened)
        {
            opened = true;
            // Show the exit popup
            $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeIn();
            $('#exitpopup').fadeIn();   
        }
    });

    $('#xmark').click(function(){
        $('#exitpopup_bg').fadeOut();
        $('#exitpopup').slideUp();
    }); 

    });
```

Answer (score 0):

use `.remove()` in the callback of `.slideup()`:

```
$('#exitpopup').slideUp('fast', function(){
    $(this).remove();
});
```